# Weird Lag Between Transitions (UIViewController -> UIViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the main view controller as a view controller with a UICollectionView, and it is populated with photos.

Once a cell is clicked on, a new view controller is pushed on the navigation stack with only a UIImageView with content mode set to aspectFit. No network related code is being executed.

For some reason the previous view is shown in the frame of the new view controller and then disappears. This occurs on the simulator and the device.

Any ideas? I have never seen this before and when I have it is usually thread related.

Link to gif of what is occurring [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EltG9.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your new viewController with the full-sized image has a transparent background, so you are able to see through it until the transition completes.  If you change the background to `UIColor.black` it will fix this issue.

Comment: You are 100% correct I did not even think about that default behavior. Thank you.